# Load vs LDAC pins

Tags: stm32, spi, dac, dsp

I'm using a TLV5628 Octal 8-bit DAC with my stm32f4-Nucleo, and I'm confused about the difference between LDAC and Load. I am also trying to figure out the clock rate, and I might just be misreading the datasheet.

Link to product page:
http://www.ti.com/product/TLV5628

Answer (score 1):

Use Load with LDAC low to load up data for one DAC and have the level change immediately.
Use Load with LDAC high to load up multiple DACs data, then pulse it low to update all output levels together.

Answer (score 0):

LOAD controls the external serial interface while LDAC controls an internal parallel data register. See the functional block diagram in the data sheet.